# GADT's: Is there a reason why the weakest or strongest type is not chosen

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, gadt

I'm reading [Fun With Phantom Types](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/With.pdf). The first exercise asks why it is necessary to provide a signature to functions operating on Phantom Types. While I cannot come up with a general reason, I do see a problem in the following example:

```
data Expr a where
  I :: Int -> Expr Int
  B :: Bool -> Expr Bool
  Add :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int
  Eq :: (Eq a) => Expr a -> Expr a -> Expr Bool


whatIs (I _) = "an integer expression"
whatIs (Add _ _) = "an adition operation"
```

Now I understand that there are two possible types for `whatIs` above, namely:

```
Expr a -> String
```

and

```
Expr Int -> String
```

however, the compiler instead gives an error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘t’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    ‘t’ is untouchable
      inside the constraints: t1 ~ Int
      bound by a pattern with constructor: I :: Int -> Expr Int,
               in an equation for ‘whatIs’
      at ti.hs:9:9-11
  ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the inferred type of whatIs :: Expr t1 -> t at ti.hs:9:1
  Possible fix: add a type signature for ‘whatIs’
• In the expression: "someString"
  In an equation for ‘whatIs’: whatIs (I _) = "someString"
• Relevant bindings include
    whatIs :: Expr t1 -> t (bound at ti.hs:9:1)
```

I'm wondering why the compiler does not choose any of the two.

Comment: Any disambiguation rule would sometimes choose the “wrong” type; that is, it would pick a type that the user did not want. The decision was to fail fast and tell the user about the ambiguity rather than sometimes do the wrong thing, which is a decision I agree with. Failing early is usually the right thing to do, in my experience, rather than trying to figure out what was actually intended and blazing ahead with a potentially wrong choice.

Comment: yeah, i would categorize this as ghc trying to behave according to the principle of least surprise

Comment: When I try to compile this, I get an error because the return values are too specific for an inferred type of `Expr t1 -> t`. That seems like a problem other than ambiguity between possible valid types.

Comment: It should compile if you add any of the types above.

Comment: @DamianNadales Yes, which makes it all the more puzzling (to me) that `Expr t1 -> t` is what is inferred.

Comment: I know I've answered this before, with essentially the same answer I wrote below (and possibly a link to a mailing list post that I learned the answer from), but I can't find it now. If somebody else manages to find the dupe, let me know -- I'll be happy to vote to close.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your example, `Expr a -> String` is a strictly better type than `Expr Int -> String`: anywhere that an `Expr Int -> String` could be used, an `Expr a -> String` will certainly do. But sometimes there *isn't* a "weakest" or "strongest" type.

Let's simplify your example even further:

```
data SoSimple a where
    SoSimple :: SoSimple Int

eval SoSimple = 3 :: Int
```

Now here are two perfectly good types to give `eval`:

```
eval :: SoSimple a -> a
eval :: SoSimple a -> Int
```

These types aren't interchangeable! Each is useful in different situations. Compare:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
import Data.Void

data SomeSimple where
    SomeSimple :: SoSimple a -> SomeSimple

-- typechecks if eval :: SoSimple a -> Int,
--    but not if eval :: SoSimple a -> a
evalSome :: SomeSimple -> Int
evalSome (SomeSimple x) = eval x

-- typechecks if eval :: SoSimple a -> a,
--    but not if eval :: SoSimple a -> Int
evalNone :: SoSimple Void -> Void
evalNone = eval
```

So neither of these is more general than the other (and it turns out that no type is more general than both while still letting `eval` itself typecheck). Since there is no most-general type for `eval`, it makes sense to refuse to pick a type and force the user to decide which of the many possible types they want this time around.